# Error Code: 1055. Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column

Tags: mysql

Trying to understand more on the below error:

"Error Code: 1055. Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'companydb.e.dno' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by"

[my data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJWpY.png)

[my resulting table after join](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHmaM.png) => Used, select dno, dnumber, dname, fname, ssn from employee, department where dno=dnumber order by dname;

From what I understood, I can use those columns in select clause which are unique to the set that has been filtered using group by and having clauses. So, here's my confusion.

Below query (to find the department with least number of employees) is failing with the above mentioned error:

```
select **dno**
from employee e, department d 
where e.dno=d.dnumber 
group by **dname** having count(ssn) =
     (select min(mycount) 
      from (select count(ssn) as mycount 
            from employee
            group by dno
           ) mytable
     );
```

But the below query (for the same requirement) is successful:

```
select **dname**
from employee e, department d 
where e.dno=d.dnumber 
group by **dno** having count(ssn) =
     (select min(mycount) 
      from (select count(ssn) as mycount 
            from employee
            group by dno
           ) mytable
     );
```

And from the data set you can understand that the dno and dname within each group  that is formed before having by are unique. So, which is it that i can select dname with group by dno but not dno with group by dname?

Comment: if you update your question and add a valid data sample the explanation of your problem should be easy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL has to decide **before** looking at the actual data if the value in your select list is *unambiguous*. It is a syntax error, not a value error.

According to the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by), Mysql will

> Reject queries for which the select list, HAVING condition, or ORDER BY list refer to nonaggregated columns that are neither named in the GROUP BY clause nor are functionally dependent on (uniquely determined by) GROUP BY columns.

"Functionally dependent on the group by columns" is a fancy way of saying: if you know the value of the grouped column, you know the value refered to in the select list without any doubt. And that is what you are saying: you assume that if you know `dname`, you know `dno` without any doubt.

But currently, nothing in your datamodel stops you from e.g. giving every department the same name. And as long as you *can* do it, MySQL has to be prepared for it (and has to reject your query, as it does not check the data). To tell MySQL that you will not/can not do that, you can define `dname` as `unique not null`. Then `dnumber`/`dno` is "uniquely determined" by `dname`, and `select dno ... group by dname` should work.

Your second query, `select dname ... group by dno` (which is equivalent to `select dname ... group by dnumber`), works because it is the primary key (and thus every value in the row is functionally dependent on it): if you know `dnumber`/`dno`, there is no ambiguity about the value of `dname`.

If you do not want to add that constraint (but are 100% certain that it *is* fulfilled, including `null`), you can also replace `select dno ... group by dname` with `select dno ... group by dno`. If `dname` actually *is* as unambiguous as you assume, this is logically equivalent (as every `dname` has one `dno` and every `dno` has one `dname`). For the same reason, you can simply use `group by dno, dname` in both cases. Alternatively, you can use e.g. `select max(dno) ... group by dname`, which also has no effect on the result, since `max()` of a distinct value is just that value.

All those means are used to inform MySQL that it can find an unambiguous value in any case, and before looking at the actual data. If your assumption is correct, it does not change the outcome (although it may have an effect on the execution plan). If it changes the resultset, your assumption wasn't correct.

Comment: Too time for me to understand your explanation but you put it excellently. So, finally, can I conclude the below:

I can use a unique non null column in the select list other than the ones that are in the group by list?

Comment: Yes exactly, a unique non-null key (in other words: a column that could have also have been your primary key instead of `dnumber`) will work. It allows you to use `group by dno` or `group by dname` in both of your queries, and you will get the exact same result! (Apart maybe from the order)

Answer (score 2):

Explored the other options and came up with the below:

The following rules apply for the columns (other than the group by column(s)) to be used in select list:

Case 1: Select involving single table

1) group by col1 => col1 has to be unique & not null or the primary key column of the corresponding table

select super_ssn from employee ... group by lname => Error

select super_ssn from employee ... group by lname (if lname is unique not null) => Success

select mgr_start_date from department ... group by dname => Error

select mgr_start_date from department ... group by dname (if dname is unique not null) => Success

2) group by col1, col2 ...  => One of col1, col2 ... should be unique not null or primary key column of the corresponding table

select super_ssn from employee ... group by sex, lname => Error

select super_ssn from employee ... group by sex, lname (if lname is unique not null) => Success

select mgr_start_date from department ... group by mgr_ssn, dname => Error

select mgr_start_date from department ... group by mgr_ssn, dname (if dname is unique not null) => Success

Case 2: Select involving multiple tables

1) group by col1 => Only columns from the same table can be used in select list if col1 is unique & not null or the primary key column of the corresponding table

select super_ssn from employee, department ... group by ssn => Success

select super_ssn from employee, department ... group by dnumber => Error

select mgr_start_date from employee, department ... group by dnumber => Success

select mgr_start_date from employee, department ... group by ssn => Error

2) group by col1, col2 ...  =>

a) Only columns from the same table as one of col1, col2 ... can be used in select list if col1/col2 ... is unique & not null or primary key column of the corresponding table

select super_ssn from employee, department ... group by ssn, dname => Success

select super_ssn from employee, department ... group by lname, dname => Error

select mgr_start_date from employee, department ... group by dnumber, lname => Success

select mgr_start_date from employee, department ... group by dname, lname => Error

b) Any column of tany able can be used if one of the group by colums is the primary of any table. This doesn't apply to the group by primary key column is part of the join condition

Ex 1: ssn even though primary key column of employee table, it can be used to select any column in any table

select mgr_start_date from department, employee ... group by ssn => Success

Ex 2: Dnumber even though primary key column of department table, it can't be used to select any column in any table since it is part of the join condition

select super_ssn from department, employee ... group by dnumber => Error

Answer (score 1):

Change the SQL Modes:

```
set global sql_mode='';
set global sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES';
```

Answer (score 0):

I do lot of research about this error and got solution that if you are select timestamp within DATE then you have to use this symbol (``) before and after of column name.
select DATE(`addedon`) as addedon, count(*) from data where id= '$bid'  GROUP BY DATE(addedon)